# Linux map usernames

Tags: linux, ldap, uid

We had an LDAP server which had our own groups and usernames on.

Now we are moving to a centrally managed LDAP server. The users now have a different username but still have a home folder mapped to that username/UID.

I wondered if there was any way that I could map/link the existing UIDs?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that they have the same numerical UID but a different username?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in unix are based on uid. So, if your users on the old ldap server and the new ldap server have the same uid they will still keep their access.
As long as the user will keep the same UID, they will be able to access the resources.
What sort of mapping would you like to do?